# What does Larger clusters allow smaller FAT tables mean?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, fat

Larger clusters allow smaller FAT tables and larger disks to be used within the
65,000-location limit. Nevertheless, **they result in wasted space at the ends of files that don’t use most of their last clusters.** What does this statement explain.

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems use a bitmaps to determine which clusters are in use (often there is are multiple such bitmaps for redundancy).

The larger the cluster size on the volume, the fewer the number of clusters on the disk, and this produces a smaller file allocation bitmap.

The size of a file in blocks is always rounded up to to a multiple of the cluster size. If you go one byte over a multiple of the cluster size, you get an entire cluster added to the file. Larger cluster sizes tend to produce more such wasted space at the end of files.

Although, in reality that space is not wasted. If you add to a file with such extra space, the file system does not have to add blocks because there is already extra to use.